# Storing a Date Property for an Azure Table Storage Entity with Mobile Services and Node.js

Tags: azure-mobile-services, azure-table-storage

I'm working with Windows Azure Mobile Services Custom APIs and the Windows Azure SDK for Node.js.

I have a simple script that starts by importing the `azure` module.

```
var azure = require('azure');
var tableService = azure.createTableService();
```

In response to a post to my custom API, I would like to insert an entity into Azure Table Storage (*not* an Azure Sql Database) with a handful of properties, one of which is a timestamp (an instance of `Date`).

```
    var entity = {
      PartitionKey: partitionKey
      RowKey: rowKey,
      Time: new Date()
    };

    tableService.insertOrReplaceEntity(tableName, entity, callback);
```

The result is that the `Time` property is stored with the entity as a string instead of a date.  For example, the `Time` property would be stored as the string `Mon Aug 12 2013 20:32:51 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)`.  I've confirmed this by loading the table from the Server Explorer in Visual Studio and examining the details of the inserted entity.

I know that you can store dates in Azure Table Storage and I've done this from C#.  However, the above does not work and I cannot think of a more canonical example to test with my custom API written in Javascript.

See also [How to Use the Table Service from Node.js](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/how-to-guides/table-services/#add-entity) which shows a similar example.

So how do you store a date property with the expected data type using the Azure Node.js SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example does save the **Time** property using the WCF **DateTime** data type. Using this code:

```
var azure = require('azure');
var tableService = azure.createTableService(accountName, accountKey, host);

tableService.createTableIfNotExists('testtable', function(error){
  if(!error){
    var item = {PartitionKey: "Things"
                , RowKey: "123"
                , name: "Thing to add"
                , category: "Test"
                , time: new Date()};
    tableService.insertOrReplaceEntity('testtable', item, function(error){
      if(!error){
        console.log('Item inserted');
        tableService.queryEntity('testtable'
          , 'Things'
          , '123'
          , function(error, entity){
              if(!error){
                  console.log(entity);
              }
          });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

If I run this code, I get:

```
Done
Item inserted
{ _:
   { 'xml:base': 'https://XXXXXX.table.core.windows.net/',
     xmlns: 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom',
     'xmlns:d': 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices',
     'xmlns:m': 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata',
     etag: 'W/"datetime\'2013-12-12T16%3A11%3A38.118877Z\'"',
     ContentRootElement: 'm:properties',
     id: 'https://XXXXXX.table.core.windows.net/testtable(PartitionKey=\'Things\',RowKey=\'123\')',
     category: { '$': [Object] },
     link: 'testtable(PartitionKey=\'Things\',RowKey=\'123\')',
     title: '',
     updated: '2013-12-12T16:11:38Z',
     author: { name: '' } },
  PartitionKey: 'Things',
  RowKey: '123',
  Timestamp: Thu Dec 12 2013 16:11:38 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time),
  category: 'Test',
  name: 'Thing to add',
  time: Thu Dec 12 2013 16:11:38 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time) }
```

This is showing a DateTime value rather than a string for the **time** field. It also shows as a DateTime field in the Visual Studio table storage viewer/editor.

If I query this same table using C# code, I also get back a C# **DateTime** value for the **time** field.

Comment: your code does not include the actual persistence method, which is hidden in Task.addTask.

Comment: I updated the example to make it a bit simpler/clearer - all the code (with the exception of the storage acccount credentials) is there.